# Vertically align inline, inline-block, and block elements

Tags: html, css

I have dynamically rendered elements that I need to align vertically. I only have editing control over the parent.

The elements don't have any white space or line break inbetween them.

I have tried with `flex`, but the `block` items contract. I have added a style attribute on the `block` elements to examplify this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>ITEM1</span><span>ITEM2</span><div style="background:pink;">ITEM3</div><div style="background:pink;">ITEM4</div><button>ITEM5</button><button>ITEM6</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `I only have editing control over the parent.` --> if you can apply CSS to parent, you can do for child? or you mean you can only add inline style? (width:100% on div element will fix the issue)

Comment: I have no access to the child code, so the inline provided in the code snippet was only to examplify what happens with flex.

Comment: I meant you can add external styles, right? you can add CSS like you did for the parent? if so, you can apply CSS to child elements

Comment: Yes, that's possible. This for example works fine `.parent > * { // some rules }`

Comment: so you can try `.parent > div {width:100%}`

Comment: Haha wow. So simple that I totally overlooked that. Thank you very much @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 0):

As per [Temani Afif's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308528/vertically-align-inline-inline-block-and-block-elements?noredirect=1#comment99227678_56308528), the following is a working solution:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

/* Setting all common block elements to width: 100% */
.parent > div, 
.parent > h1, 
.parent > h2, 
.parent > h3, 
.parent > h4, 
.parent > h5, 
.parent > h6
.parent > ol, 
.parent > ul,
.parent > pre,
.parent > address,
.parent > blockquote,
.parent > dl,
.parent > fieldset,
.parent > form,
.parent > hr,
.parent > noscript,
.parent > table {
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>ITEM1</span><span>ITEM2</span><div style="background:pink;">ITEM3</div><div style="background:pink;">ITEM4</div><button>ITEM5</button><button>ITEM6</button>
</div>
```